# count using two tables in and display 0 for no result SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been struggling and would really appreciate some assistance:

I have two tables flights and carriers.

**flights**

```
Flight_ID | Airport_Origin | Airport_Destination | Carrier_ID 
1 | DOM | IAD | 1
2 | IAD | DOM | 4
3 | BAL | UEI | 1
4 | LAX | CHI | 2
5 | VAS | SDA | 3
6 | MUM | PAR | 2
7 | LAD | BOS | 4
```

**carriers**

```
carrier_ID | Carrier_Name
1 | American 
2 | southwest
3 | delta
4 | united
5 | spirit
```

I would like to display each airline carrier by its name with a count of number of flights. And if the airline has no flights, it should show 0 and should display all carriers.

Output should be:

```
CarrierName | NumberofFlights
American    | 2
southwest   | 2
delta       | 1
united      | 2
spirit      | 0
```

my code:

```
select carriers.Carrier_Name AS 'Carrier Name', count(*) AS 'Number of Flights'
from flights 
inner join carriers
on flights.Carrier_ID = carriers.Carrier_ID
group by Carrier_Name 
Order BY Carrier_Name
;
```

I cannot seem to show the carrier with no flights as 0. My output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `LEFT JOIN` (outer join) when records from right part of join may not exist:

```
select
  c.Carrier_Name AS 'Carrier Name', count(f.Flight_ID) AS 'Number of Flights'
from carriers c
left join flights f on f.Carrier_ID = c.Carrier_ID
group by Carrier_Name 
order by Carrier_Name
```

also this can be accomplished by such a subquery:

```
select
  c.Carrier_Name AS 'Carrier Name', 
  (select count(*) from flights f where f.Carrier_ID = c.Carrier_ID)  AS 'Number of Flights'
from carriers c
order by Carrier_Name
```

`INNER JOIN` means that corresponding records from both parts of join **must** exist.

Comment: `count(*)` is wrong in the `left join` query, it needs to be `count(f.something)`.

Comment: Thanks for the assistnace Ivan!  I have not used a subquery before and this works as a great example. Also thanks for the tip on when to use inner join.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an outer join so the result will include rows with no match. And then the `COUNT` function has to count a row in the `flights` table so it won't count the null row that results when there's no match.

```
SELECT c.carrier_name AS `Carrier Name`, COUNT(f.Flight_ID) AS `Number of Flights`
FROM carriers AS c
LEFT JOIN flights AS f ON f.carrier_ID = c.carrier_ID
GROUP BY c.carrier_name
ORDER BY c.carrier_name
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance! that makes more sense now!